# Some issues trying to read a file with cbc.read.table function in R + using filter while reading files

Tags: r

a)I'm trying to read a relatively big .txt file with the function `cbc.read.table` from the `colbycol` package in R. According to what I've been reading this package makes job easier when we have large files (more than a GB to be read in R) and we don't need all of the columns/variables for our analysis. Also, I read that the function `cbc.read.table` could support the same `read.table`'s parameters. However, if I pass the parameter `nrows` (in order to get a preview of my file in R) I get the following error:

```
#My line code. I'm just reading columns 5,6,7,8 out of 27
i.can <- cbc.read.table( "xxx.txt", header = T, sep = "\t",just.read=5:8, nrows=20)
#error message
Error in read.table(file, nrows = 50, sep = sep, header = header, ...) : 
formal argument "nrows" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

So, my question is: could you tell me how can I solve this problem?

b) After that, I tried to read all instances with the following code:

```
i.can.b <- cbc.read.table( "xxx.txt", header = T, sep = "\t",just.read=4:8) #done perfectly
my.df <- as.data.frame(i.can.b) #getting error in this line
Error in readSingleKey(con, map, key) : unable to obtain value for key 'Company' #Company is a string column in my data set
```

So, my question is again: How can I solve this?

c) Do you know a way in which I can filter (by conditions on instances) while reading files?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a preview, then just use `read.table` with nrow=20 and the colClasses argument set to read your columns.